# How to scroll with in the chrome browser window

Tags: c#, selenium

How to scroll to the bottom of the license agreement, which will enable the Accept button? The browser itself does not have a scroll bar; only the agreement has it.
I have googled and tried many different solutions and still can not move the scroll bar., at all.
C# code I've tried. I also tried many other and none is working. Anyone has any idea how to make it work?

******IWebElement ScrollBar => DriverContext.Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='frm-scrollbar height-with-eula']"));
Actions act = new Actions(DriverContext.Driver);
act.MoveToElement(ScrollBar).ClickAndHold(ScrollBar).MoveByOffset(0, 1000).Release().Perform();******

What Im trying to scroll:

[image]

Html for the scroll bar section:
[image]

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/

Comment: Send it a bunch of PageDown ?

Comment: @user9938 I'm using Chrome and Selenium, not Edge ( atleast for now). ot sure this will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used this to scroll to the bottom of the page. This works for areas where the scroll bar is inside the webpage itself. Used this in multiple pages for scrolling.

```
EventFiringWebDriver ef = new(Driver);
// cssStr is the css for the area that includes the scroll bar
cssStr = "div[class=\\\"max-h-370 overflow-y-auto pl-24 pr-24\\\"]";
// 10000 or any number depending on scroll distance in pixels
ef.ExecuteScript("document.querySelector('" + cssStr + "').scrollTop = 10000");

IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)DriverContext.Driver;
// by is to be constructed and passed
IWebElement ele = Driver.FindElement(by);
js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", ele);
```